# 'Invalid Formula' in dplyr mutate function for rowwise() linear regression across a data frame with multiple models. Where is this error coming from?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, lm

I saw an article on Towards Data Science about a cool technique to run multiple linear regressions using functions from the dplyr and broom packages with a data frame consisting of model formulas. I tried this first with my own data to no avail so I copied the example right from the post and received the same error! You can look at the post here: https://towardsdatascience.com/five-things-you-never-knew-you-could-do-with-dplyr-1b634c0ea745

Here is the code from the post using the cars package mtcars dataset.

```
# create a column with model formulas to test
models <- data.frame(
  formula = c(
    "mpg ~ cyl",
    "mpg ~ cyl + disp",
    "mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp",
    "mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat"
  )
)
# run them all and get fit statistics
models %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars))
  )
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x invalid formula
ℹ Input `..1` is `broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars))`.
ℹ The error occured in row 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x invalid formula
ℹ Input `..1` is `broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars))`.
ℹ The error occured in row 1.
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::rowwise(.)
  9. dplyr::mutate(., broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars)))
 11. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
```

I can see the model in the data frame just fine. And I can do a rowwise() view of the data as well. I tried restarting my R session and loading only the dplyr, broom, and cars packages to see if there was any masking issues (which there shouldn't be since I'm calling the functions directly anyway...).

I tried using mutate_at(), because I'm aware that sending strings through functions can sometimes be problematic in the tidyverse, and I received this error:

```
> # run them all and get fit statistics
> models %>%
+   dplyr::rowwise() %>%
+   dplyr::mutate_at(
+     broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars))
+   )
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

The only issue is with mutate, but it seems to work just fine as it is coded here for the author of the article.
Any ideas about what's going on would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
RStudio version 1.4
Package versions: dplyr - 1.0.5, tidyverse - 1.3.0, broom - 0.7.5

Comment: Please check the `packageVersion('dplyr')` it works for me with 1.0.4.  May be in your code, wrap the `broom::glance(lm(formula, mtcars)` in a `list`

Comment: @IRTFM can you not? I'm using Rstudio 1.4, I have dplyr version 1.0.5, but all other package versions mentioned are the same. I tried wrapping with list and I still get the same error

Comment: My reading of the package description of tidyverse 1.3.0 is that it has a much later version of dplyr. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/index.html